# How can i filter a datetime column in informix with a date

Tags: sql, informix

I'd like to filter a datetime column in informix 12.10.

I got the following "test" table

| name | insert_date | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2022-04-06 11:03:22.000 | .... |
| ... | 2022-03-02 12:03:22.000 | .... |
| ... | 2021-02-04 11:15:22.000 | .... |
| ... | 2021-01-05 11:03:22.000 | .... |

My approach is the following

```
SELECT * FROM test where insert_date < "01.01.2022"
```

I got the error:
`SQL-Error [IX000]: Non-numeric character in datetime or interval.`

How can i filter a datetime column with a date (without time) in informix?

Comment: One problem is that you are comparing a DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION column with a string, not a DATE, and the server therefore attempts to convert the string to a DATETIME, but it isn't in the correct format.  You can force the interpretation as a DATE in multiple ways: `WHERE DATE(insert_date) < DATE("01.01.2022")` is one possibility, explicitly converting both operands to a DATE; another is `WHERE insert_date < MDY(1, 1, 2022)` (which has the benefit of using a locale-insensitive way of specifying the date). There are other options too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://informix.hcldoc.com/12.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1600.htm) that should be<sup>1</sup>

```sql
select *
  from TEST
 where INSERT_DATE < DATETIME (2022-1-1) YEAR TO DAY
```

<sup>1</sup> Assuming that the data type of column INSERT_DATE is [DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION](https://informix.hcldoc.com/12.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1600.htm).

Comment: What does "YEAR TO DAY" mean?

Comment: @VK_ON_STACKOVERFLOW `YEAR TO DAY` is part of the DATETIME literal as explained in the documentation that I linked to in my answer. Did you not read the documentation?